# click textfield to copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out how to make it so if i click the textbox, it copies the content of it to clipboard. I found some scripts online, but they make a popup display that it has been copied.

Is there an easier way to do it with javascript or jquery 1.7.2?

http://jsfiddle.net/vUBhd/

```
        <div id="select_text"><div id="link_image"><img src="images/link-chain.jpg" width="29" height="37" alt="Select Text" /></div>
        <input id="linkText" class="linkText" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="copytextinfo">Click in the text area to copy to clipboard.</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use ZClip http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#link_image').zclip({
        path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:$('#linkText').text(),
        afterCopy:function(){
               $("#message").text("Copied to Clip Board");
            }
    });
```

Comment: But that one shows a message it has copied to clipboard. I dont want one is the issue.

Comment: Just Remove the afterCopy: Or leve the block empty. that will solve your problem

Comment: path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf' Make sure this path is correct.